# Truffle compiler can't find open zeppelin contracts

Tags: solidity

I get an error message when I try to compile. I checked inside node_modules and all the contracts are there. im running truffle with sudo. Its not this just this import all open zeppelin contracts are doing this.

```
Error: Could not find /home/a/Documents/so/contracts/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol from any sources; imported from /home/a/Documents/so/contracts/crowdsale.sol
    at Resolver.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:53:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:5:42)
    at <anonymous>
Truffle v5.1.28 (core: 5.1.28)
Node v8.10.0
```

I'm importing like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@` syntax to import:

`import "@openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";`

See examples here:

https://github.com/Dawn-Protocol/dawn-erc20-erc777/blob/master/contracts/DawnTokenImpl.sol#L5

Comment: that does not work they install into node_modues with missing contracts

Comment: The repository is a working example, so you can try to narrow down why it does not work for you by comparing your work to this one. Maybe, for example, Solidity compiler version is different and you are using too old compiler?

Comment: Also study how Solidity handles relative import paths and what `@` symbol means. Your question lacks any description of your project folder structure or the evidence that the contract should be there where you think it is, so I think it is just a misundertanding on your behalf you think it should work.

Comment: There is an open issue about it on windows!